# Android program launch failure in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying out an `android` program for `Hello World` in `eclipse`. But while launching the emulator the following message is displayed :-

```
[2016-05-21 15:00:58 - HelloWorldApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2016-05-21 15:00:58 - HelloWorldApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2016-05-21 15:00:58 - HelloWorldApp] Launch canceled!
```

How can I deal with the above problem ????

EDIT :-

I even tried using the `-partition-size 1024` trick but it failed too. So what am I supposed to do now ???

Comment: Your debugging device have no sufficient storage to run your app

Comment: @Manifest how can i ensure that the debugging device has sufficient memory

Comment: just try to clear your device cache/uninstall some apps for creating space to install app

Comment: @Ankit Acharya it is clearly written in your log INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

You may check like this create one class that extends Application

```
class EnsureSpace extends Application{
//Something like this should work:
                    StatFs stat = new
StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                    long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *
(long)stat.getBlockCount();
                    long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;

if(megAvailable > yoursize){

}
else{
//exit app
}

}
```

Comment: I want a solution dude, not a checking code